# login form submit results in authentication failed in codeigniter 3.1.2

Tags: php, codeigniter

my validations are working ok but after that userid and password results empty in model fit_reg_model and it results into authentication failed.please help me out.
this is my code :

model fit_reg_model
`

class Ftg_reg_model extends CI_Model {

```
public function log_valid( $userid, $password )
{

    $this->db->select("regID,loginCode");
    $whereCondition = $array = array('regID' =>$userid,'loginCode'=>$password);
    $this->db->where($whereCondition);
    $this->db->from('fit_1login');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    ////////////////////////////////checking values////////////////////
    echo"<pre>";
               print_r ($query->result()); exit;
               return $query->row()->countID;




     if( $query->num_rows() )
           {

            echo"<pre>";
               print_r ($query->result()); exit;
               return $query->row()->countID;
               //return TRUE;
           }
             else
           {
               return FALSE;
           }
}
```

}
contrller fit_ci
` public function fit_loguser()
    {
       $this->load->library('form_validation');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','User Id','required|valid_email|valid_emails|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','required|trim');
       $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters("","

");

```
    if($this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        $userid = $this->input->post('uname');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        //////////////////////////////////////loding model////////////////
        $this->load->model('ftg_reg_model');

         //echo $userid , $password;

        if( $this->ftg_reg_model->log_valid('$userid','$password')== True )
        {
          //$this->load->view('fitasy/fit_userprofile'); 
            $this->load->library('session');
            $this->session->set_userdata('id',$id);
            echo "Successful loged";

        }
        else
        {
         echo "Authentication failed";
        }
    }
    else
    {
      $data['title'] = 'Fit';
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->view('fit/index.php',$data);


    }
}
```

`

view fit_loguser
`
        Login here to add items to your Cart
       
        'form-horizontal'])?>

```
           <?php echo form_error('uname'); ?>
           <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'uname','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username','value'=>set_value('uname')])?><br>

           <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
           <?php echo form_password(['name'=>'password','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Password'])?><br>

           <?php echo form_submit(['name'=>'logsubmit','class'=>'btn btn-default','value'=>'Proceed','type'=>'submit'])?>

    <?php echo form_close()?><!-------------form close-------------------------------------->

</div>`
```

Comment: Please format your question.

Comment: ok i will , new to stakoverflow

Comment: That's why telling you.

Comment: where to edit or i have to post it again?

Comment: Edit option is there below the question tag. Got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove

```
$this->db->select("regID,loginCode");
```

In your model to see what's happening